# AGM point-counting algorithm

Tags: ring-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm currently working on an implementation of a simple ElGamal ECC protocol, and I need to implement a point-counting algorithm to calculate the order of an elliptic curve group. I've chosen to implement the AGM algorithm by Mestre described in this paper: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-36178-2_20

At the moment I have the coefficients of my elliptic curve in $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$, but it seems to me that the calculations done in the algorithm are done with elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^m}$ (or the polynomials with 2-adic number coefficients). I would like to understand what is meant when the author says:

> The ring $\mathbb{Z}_q$ comes with the natural "reduction modulo 2" homomorphism onto $\mathbb{F}_q$. For $x\in\mathbb{Z}_q$, the notation $x\bmod 2$ means the element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ image of $x$ by this homomorphism.

When describing the AGM algorithm, the author mentions:

> Let $a_6$ be an element of $\mathbb{F}^*_q\hspace{0.5em}$ ... $\hspace{0.5em}$ We denote also by $a_6$ an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ that reduces to $a_6$ modulo 2.

My question is how does such an element reduce to an element of $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: They are using the symbol $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$ for the local ring that is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the degree $n$ unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_2$.  So the residue field $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}/((2\mathbb{Z}_2)\mathbb{Z}_{2^n})$ is the degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb{Z}_2/(2\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong\mathbb{F}_2$, i.e., $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, and that is the "reduction mod 2" homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{2^m}\to\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you maybe provide me with a small example?

Comment: We know the degree $n$ unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is adjoining a (hence all) primitive $(p^n-1)$-th root of unity.  So as an example, we have $\mathbb{Q}_2(\zeta_3)/\mathbb{Q}_2$ is the unramified quadratic extension, and it is easy to check $\mathbb{Z}_{2^2}=\mathbb{Z}_2[\zeta_3]$.  Reducing mod $2$ is exactly what you expect: $a+b\zeta_3$ maps to $\bar{a}+\bar{b}X\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(X^2+X+1)\cong\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$, and $\bar{a},\bar{b}$ the reduction mod 2 of $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_2$.